Book where the populace is split between two sects, that of the “hand” and that of the “mind"
I am searching for a certain fictional book. In it the populace is split between two sects, that of the “hand” and that of the “mind.” Modern technologies and things that could be considered innovative are banned and people are prosecuted for them. The story begins with a child’s parents being taken away or killed because they managed to create a rudimentary hoeing tool for the use in their garden. I believe after this, one of the children is identified to have powers of the “mind” and is take away to be trained. I believe the title is something like “The Hand of the Stone,” or something like that. I’ve tried searching the internet to no avail. I would really enjoy to read this again. Hope someone out there knows this one. Thanks in advance for at least reading this

One of these? https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=the+hand&type=Fiction+Titles

The Arm of the Stone by Victoria Strauss.


Long ago, when the worlds were one...
So begins the Tale, the ancestral legend Bron's family has guarded for a thousand years. Once, they were the keepers of the Stone, the most sacred object on earth, from which all the powers of Mind are drawn. But when the conflict between Mind and Hand split the worlds apart, the Stone was seized by an ambitious sorcerer. To keep the new world from contamination, he created rigid Limits circumscribing which tools might be made and which knowledge might be pursued-laws brutally enforced by a group of Guardians known as the Arm of the Stone.
For centuries, Bron's family has concealed the secret of its heritage. But when Bron's brother invents a new kind of plow-an unpardonable heresy in the world of the Guardians-the Arm of the Stone reaches in once again to tear them apart. Fleeing for his life, Bron vows revenge. To strike the Guardians down, he will become a Guardian himself. But Bron cannot know how much that choice will change him. Nor does he anticipate the hatred of a powerful enemy, or the love of a beautiful Guardian named Liliane...whose mission is to destroy him.

I found it by using ISFDB to search for titles ending with "the stone" then going through the results looking for any likely culprits. It was sheer luck that your book appeared near the top of the list.

Thank you so much! I appreciate your help
